# Replacement for SearchSourceBuilder class in java api client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apiclient

I am migrating a java application from elastic search high level client to java api client.
There is a SearchSourceBuilder class in elastic search java high level client.
But I couldn't find any corresponding class in java api client.
Can someone help on this?
Old code snippet is as below.

```
BoolQuery.Builder builder = QueryBuilders.bool();
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
```

Comment: Can you please add your old code sinppets ?

Comment: BoolQuery.Builder builder = QueryBuilders.bool();
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write bool query as shown below in new Java client. as far as i know `SearchSourceBuilder` is not available in new client.

```java
Query termQuery = TermQuery.of(t -> t.field("field_name").value("search_value"))._toQuery();

SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(r -> r.query(q -> q.bool(b -> b.must(termQuery))));
```